# How to get GAP to recognize Read("filename.g") when called using a python sub-process

Tags: python, subprocess, gap-system

I'm doing research in computational number theory and I use a software package called GAP (Groups, Algebra and Programming). I want to set up a system in which I can call a python script to perform all of the set-up for me so that I can run multiple computations overnight.

To do this, I put the functions I need to define into some .g files. The command to call these functions in GAP is simply:

```
Read("prelimcode1.g");
```

When I try this in the gap environment, it performs the setup for me. However, when I try to use python to read these files, I get a strange error in my GAP environment.

Most of the fixes I've attempted have involved reorganizing the way in which I call the Read("file"); statement.

```
def gapCaller():
    GAPpath = r'C:\gap-4.10.1\bin\gap.bat'
    deltasets= r'C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\deltasetfunctions\deltasetsinit.g'
    sp.Popen([GAPpath,deltasets])
```

My expected result would be that GAP would simply read the files. However, I get the following error message

```
>Syntax error: expression expected in 
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\deltasetfunctions\deltasetsinit.g:1    
>Read("prelimcode1.g");  
>Read("prelimcode2.g");  
>Read("prelimcode3.g");  
>Read("prelimcode4.g");
```

with an indicator pointing to the first R.

Comment: Have you seen this (first result when Googling for your error message)? https://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2018/005662.html

Comment: What's the content of `deltasetsinit.g`?